# PL/SQL - how do you get the "first()" row to show and tell it to not count null values?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to PL/SQL but do have experience with Proc SQL (SAS).  In the past, whenever I have "counted" a specific variable, it would skip over null values.  In PL/SQL, however, I noticed that it still counts them.

example query (counting nulls in pl/sql):

```
select 
  month, 
  count(et_referral_traffic) as refer, 
  count(et_direct_traffic)   as direct, 
  count(et_organic_search)   as organic, 
  count(et_olavisit)         as visit, 
  count(et_olaimpression)    as olai, 
  count(et_paid_search)      as paid
from
(
  select distinct 
    userid, 
    extract(month from timestamp) as month, 
    et_referral_traffic, 
    et_direct_traffic, 
    et_organic_search, 
    et_olavisit, 
    et_olaimpression, 
    et_paid_search
  from 
    EPIPEN_CLEAN_20150607
)
group by month;
```

Additionally, I was always able to select a specific variable and then aggregate another variable by selecting First(variable_name), so I would get the first row of that variable_name and order it by whatever other variable I needed to get the right one.

EXAMPLE:

```
select first_entry, count(touchpointid) as total_entries
from
(
select touchpointid, sessionid, first(revisedentrytype) as first_entry, et_key_action
from epipen_clean_20150607
   group by sessionid, touchpointid
   order by sessionid, touchpointid
)
group by first_entry;
```

This second query is the one I am most confused about, as I was always able to do this type of query in other forms of SQL.  Any help at all as to how I could rewrite this to work in PL SQL would be greatly appreciated!!

Thank you!!!

Comment: You say PL/SQL but you only use SQL select statements as examples. Can you set up a test case to show what you expect and what you want?

Comment: Q1: SQL aggregates always ignore NULLs, so this should be the same result. Q2: The `FIRST_VALUE` windowed aggregate function might be what you need.

Comment: In the second query you need to provide an alias for the derived table, i.e. `from ( select touchpointid, .... ) x ...`

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need PL/SQL - you can do it using SQL using `MIN() KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ... )` [documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm) and another explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20157109/1509264)]:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4bb30/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE epipen_clean_20150607 ( touchpointid, sessionid, revisedentrytype, time ) AS
          SELECT 1,1,'A', DATE '2015-01-02' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1,1,'B', DATE '2015-01-01' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1,2,'A', DATE '2015-01-01' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1,2,'B', DATE '2015-01-02' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2,1,'A', DATE '2014-12-31' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2,1,'B', DATE '2015-01-01' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2,2,'A', DATE '2015-01-02' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select first_entry, count(touchpointid) as total_entries
from
(
  select touchpointid,
         sessionid,
         MIN(revisedentrytype) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY time ) AS first_entry
  from epipen_clean_20150607
     group by sessionid, touchpointid
     order by sessionid, touchpointid
)
group by first_entry
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4bb30/1/0)**:

```
| FIRST_ENTRY | TOTAL_ENTRIES |
|-------------|---------------|
|           B |             1 |
|           A |             3 |
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL `count()` aggregate function ignores `null` values passed as argument, check [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e1e75/2).

To get first value you need [`first_value`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions059.htm#SQLRF00642) analytic function, but as in any functions which implies ordering you need to specify how to order a values. You can find example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a0b4b/5).

But as follows from your example with `group by` without specifying any ordering you just need to use a [`min()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions100.htm#SQLRF00667) aggregate function to get a minimal (or first) value within a group:

```
select 
  first_entry, 
  count(touchpointid) as total_entries
from
(
  select 
    touchpointid, 
    sessionid, 
    min(revisedentrytype) as first_entry, 
    et_key_action
  from 
    epipen_clean_20150607
   group by sessionid, touchpointid
)
group by first_entry;
```