# Oracle Statement with DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, dense-rank

Can somebody tell me how I can convert the following Oracle SQL Statement in Postgres SQL? I don't get it...

```
SELECT MIN(t2.id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY t2.edit_date) AS id 
  FROM temp t2 
 GROUP BY t2.sku
```

Comment: Have a look on that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145952/partition-by-with-and-without-keep-in-oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(t2.id) OVER (ORDER BY t2.edit_date) AS id 
FROM temp t2 
GROUP BY t2.sku
```

---

**EDIT:**

Even though above did what OP asked, the equivalent for the given query can be:

```
select min(t.id) id 
from
  (select t.*,
   dense_rank() over (order by t.edit_date) AS rnk 
   from temp t) t
where rnk = 1
group by t.sku;
```

Comment: This worked for me - thanks. But I needed to add the other columns in the Group by

Comment: Please post the data and expected output in question and we'll be able to help you on that

Comment: This is odd... isn't this an analytic function in PostgreSQL, just like in Oracle? If it is, then it's not the equivalent of the Oracle statement in the original question. (But hey, the OP thinks it is, so why argue...)

Comment: You are right - I was too fast. The edited question is correct. It's just a part of a statement. I delete all duplicated products except the oldest. And this part of the Statement should deliver me the oldest one.