# Apply MAX value. Then add conditions based on the MAX Value Row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table. I need the `MAX` value of Date Per ID when CategoryID = 201 Per ID

TableA

```
ID    Date       CategoryID
 1     1/1/17        101
 1     1/2/17        201
 1     1/4/17        201
 1     1/5/17        301
 2     1/1/17        101
 2     5/1/17        201
```

(Work) Query:

```
   ,MAX(TABLEA.DATE)  
    KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY TABLEA.DATE)
    OVER (PARTITION BY ID)
    AS most_recent_dt
```

I need to add a condition in the query: When CategoryId = 201 Then take the `MAX` Date

Expected Output:

```
ID    Date    CatergoryId    Most_Recent_Dt
 1     1/1/17        101       1/4/17
 1     1/2/17        201       1/4/17
 1     1/4/17        201       1/4/17
 1     1/5/17        301       1/4/17
 2     1/1/17        101       5/1/17
 2     5/1/17        201       5/1/17
```

***Edit**

Now that I have my MAX Line I need to add Conditions based on the MAX line only.

Expected Output:

In short.

**Partition by ID.

Apply Max Value when CategoryID = 201

Now apply conditions based off the MAX value ROW

When Role = Gold and HistID is not null Then "Approved"

else "Pending"

```
ID   Date   CategoryID    Most_Recent_Dt    Role    HistId    Category
 1     1/1/17        101       1/4/17       Gold   (Null)      Approved
 1     1/2/17        201       1/4/17       Bronze   201       Approved
 *1     1/4/17        201       1/4/17       Gold     101       Approved
 1     1/5/17        301       1/4/17       Gold     101       Approved
 2     1/1/17        101       5/1/17       Gold    (Null)     Pending 
 *2     5/1/17        201       5/1/17       Bronze   101       Pending
```

Comment: What do you want to happen when the condition is not met?

Comment: Good question: Then 'Not met'. Can a Case Expression be embedded so I can control when the condition is not met?

Comment: I've update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need the `KEEP` clause (since it is the same as the `MAX`) and can just do:

```
 MAX( CASE When CategoryId = 201 THEN TABLEA.DATE END )
   OVER (PARTITION BY ID)
   AS most_recent_201_dt
```

> Now that I have my MAX Line I need to add Conditions based on the MAX line only.
>
> ```
> Case When (Role = Gold And HistId IS NOT NULL) OR () THEN 'Approved' WHEN... THEN 'NotApproved' ELSE 'Pending' END AS Category
> ```

This is when you would use the `KEEP` clause as you want the values for the `Role` and `HistID` columns for the latest date value.

Something like:

```
CASE
WHEN (
  MAX( CASE Role WHEN 'Gold' THEN Role END )
    KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST
           ORDER BY CASE WHEN CategoryId = 201 THEN TABLEA.DATE END NULLS FIRST )
    OVER ( PARTITION BY ID )
  = Role
  AND
  MAX( HistID )
    KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST
           ORDER BY CASE WHEN CategoryId = 201 THEN TABLEA.DATE END NULLS FIRST,
                    CASE Role WHEN 'Gold' THEN Role END NULLS FIRST )
    OVER ( PARTITION BY ID )
  IS NOT NULL
)
OR ( ... )
THEN 'Approved'
WHEN ...
THEN 'NotApproved'
ELSE 'Pending'
END
```

Comment: Thanks, When would one use the Keep Clause?

Comment: @JoJo I have [an explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145952/partition-by-with-and-without-keep-in-oracle/20157109#20157109) but the short version is use `KEEP` when you want to first filter by one set of columns (the `KEEP` clause) and then get the maximum from only one of those columns (or a different column).

Comment: You can also make mistakes using `KEEP` with the wrong `FIRST`/`LAST` clause; so, if you don't need it don't include it. For example: `MAX( col ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY col )` will get the maximum of the kept values but the kept values are the minimum rows so that will actually return the minimum (not the maximum). Similarly, `MAX( col ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY col DESC )` will also return the minimum (since the kept rows are ordered in descending order this time).

Comment: Thanks. I've added other conditions into my ask.

Comment: @JoJo Updated (I think it will work if you fill in the `...` sections but it is untested)

Comment: this runs but I don't understand the syntax. So instead of using only MAX we are embedding the Keep clause. What does = Role mean. We are taking the MAX of when Role is Gold. Then performing analytics on that row, correct?

Comment: Also, I'm unclear why we apply the MAX function on HistId

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN CategoryId = 201 THEN TABLEA.DATE END) OVER (PARTITION BY id) as most_recent_dt
```

That is, don't think of this as a "first value" calculation.  Think of it as a (condition) maximum over all records with the same `id`.