# What are difference between KEEP and OVER in Oracle analytic SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

What are the difference between KEEP and OVER keyword in Oracle analytic SQL.

Comment: Do you have a sample query to differentiate?

Comment: `keep()` is used for aggregate functions, while `over()` is used for analytical (aka "window") functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep and OVER clause can be used in same query or individually. While OVER clause is used to work over analytical functions KEEP is used with DENSE_RANK FIRST to KEEP the value of FIRST row in DENSE_RANK.

Please refer to below post for detailed explanation.

[POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145952/partition-by-with-and-without-keep-in-oracle)