# Oracle to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, oracle

Can somebody tell me how I can convert the following Oracle SQL Statement in PostgreSQL? I don't get it...

```
 SELECT 
     MAX(TKI1.USER_ID)
     KEEP(DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY TKI1.UPD_DATE NULLS FIRST)
     OVER(PARTITION BY TKI1.NUMBER) AS  USER_ID         
 FROM
    USER_TABLE TKI1;
```

Comment: Start with the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20157109/15603477

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN rnk = 1 THEN user_id END) OVER (PARTITION BY NUMBER)
         AS user_id
FROM   (
  SELECT user_id,
         NUMBER,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY NUMBER ORDER BY UPD_DATE DESC NULLS LAST)
           AS rnk
  FROM   user_table
) t
```